# What Type does Powershells `Get-Member` show

Tags: powershell

I use PowerShell to write a database exporter.

I have `DataRow`s, serialized via `Export-Clixml 'data.xml'`. These DataRows have a column `value`.

I read the first row via `$row = (Import-Clixml 'data.xml')[0]`.

If I check for it's Type, via `$row.value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` I get True

If I use `Get-Member` on value, like `$row.value | Get-Member`, I get the Output

```
 TypeName: Deserialized.System.DBNull
```

I kind of expected this to be `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`.

**Where does the type `Get-Member` shows me come from?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `$row.value.PSObject.TypeNames` you'll probably see that `Deserialized.System.DBNull` is the first in the list.

Also see [this answer from Keith Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12682824/3905079) and the [MSDN on the TypeNames property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject.typenames(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Do I correctly understand that the actual object is 'wrapped' with the PSObject? Is there a way to "unwrap" it?

Comment: @keppla yes it's wrapped. Unwrapping it can be tricky. It often depends on *what* you want to do with it exactly. Explicitly unwrapping may not be necessary. It might be best to edit this into the question or post a new question, but could you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: I guess you're right that that would be the scope of another question. Basically, I have to create an Query, and I need to handle the values depending on their type (which is, thanks to your answer, now possible for me). Thanks!